# Magento 2 - many attribute set, bad admin catalog perfomace

Tags: catalog, backend, performance, attribute-set

I'm using Magento 2.1.3. Everything had worked ok till I've imported bunch of attributes and attribute sets. Now I have 74 attribute set, and 705 attributes.
I've imported these via Store Manager.

After that, if I want to open Product->Catalog admin page, it's need 5 min to load all products (there are only 5 product). Can be root cause for these bad import of attribute sets via Store Manager or it's something else?

How I can debug this page to see which take this much time. I can go vie xdebug, but I don't know where to put breakpoint. Any hint will be helpful. Which function is responsible to load products on Product->Catalog page?

Thank you.